# continuous vs discrete simulation in robotics

Tags: control, simulation

As far as I know, a robot sends orders as discrete signals. However, isn't computer simulation based on continuous simulation? Do you know if it may happen any important difference when comparing reality to simulation in some cases? I heard that cable-driven robots were quite sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer simulations are not done in the continuous time domain. Simulator designers approximate continuous simulation by reducing the difference between consecutive discrete time points to such a low level that it "looks like" continuous simulation.

If you are modelling something in a 'pseudo continuous' simulator, the best way to get similar results in a hardware implementation would be to increase the frequency of your control signals.